# How to Destroy session after session timeout

Tags: java, session

I use a javascript ajax to check the sessoin status every 5 seconds .   if the server get null from session,the js will redirect to login page.

And I set `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.my.project.listener.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<session-config>
<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
<cookie-config>
  <http-only>true</http-only>
</cookie-config>
```

`SessionListener.java`:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
  logger.debug("sessionCreated");
}

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        HttpSession session = httpSessionEvent.getSession();
        //String username = (String) session.getAttribute("s_userId");
        logger.debug(s_userId+"sessionDestroyed!。");
        session.invalidate();
        logger.debug(s_userId+"is session really Destroyed??");
      }

}
```

But after one minute . it still not logout.
How could destroy session after one minute??

I print the log after `session.invalidate();`
But it still can get `s_userID`
What's wrong?

And My second question is I use `<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>` But it seems it did not extend times if the user do something on web. It just count 1 minute and then countdown.  is it right?

Comment: Try clearing out the browser cache :) you might be getting that page due to the caching too

Comment: I try. And I found that seems the ````session.invalidate();```` not working

Comment: If you check the session every 5 seconds, the inactive time is restarted. Your session will never timeout. The `sessionDestroyed` is called if a session is invalidated, so you are invalidating an invalid session. It doesn't make sense. Also it is about 1 minute depending on the schedule of the session clearing thread in your app server.

Comment: What's the good method to redirect to login page if the user didn't do anything after 1 minute ?? Will ````session.getMaxInactiveInterval()```` restarted  the inactive time or it just logout after one minute??